# update iphone app "CodeResources file must be a symbolic link"

Tags: iphone, distribution, deployment, codesign

I tried to update an iphone app, which lies in an other "itunes connect" profile. I used "application loader" and everything is fine until I try to upload the zip file

I get this strange message and cant figure out whats going wrong

> "The CodeResources file must be a symbolic link to _CodeSignature/CodeResources"

I opened the bundle and the folder _CodeSignature is there.

I compiled the app with my distribution profile (no problems)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you zipping it? I'm betting that FooApp.app/CodeResources is a file, not a symlink.

If you're using command-line "zip", you need to use `zip -y -r` to preserve the symlink.

Comment: zipped with right click.
after deleting the build in the organizer and just plain rebuilding it - it worked.

but thanks for the zip tip anyway

Comment: Also, if you're using cp to copy it somewhere before zipping, that can screw up the symlinks. Use cp -R.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with XCode 3.2.5 (new submission interface), and all it took was to:

1. delete the build folder
2. clean, and then
3. build and archive again.

Comment: Worked exactly for me. Recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. But then I noticed that I was building in **release mode** *to the simulator*, and not a device. When I *targeted a device*, I got the proper application file, which I then zipped with the iTunes Artwork and submitted without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here but I "fixed" it after I changed the "Deployment Target" from 2.0 to 3.0 in the target I was building and removed the "Architectures" to only armv6 (before I had both armv6 and armv7). Finally I had to put 'No' to 'Build Active Architecture Only'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the command line:

```
cd (to where your project is)
ln -s _CodeSignature/CodeResources CodeResources
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out why I keep getting this error for every binary I create. I've followed all the standard procedures (double-checking my project settings, deleting build folders, cleaning all targets, removing and reinstalling certificates and provisioning profiles, creating and installing new certificates and provisioning profiles, repairing disk permissions, etc) but none of them seem to solve the problem.

I think the problem is that my XCode installation is unable to create symbolic links. I might reinstall it (or even OS X) to see if that fixes the issue permanently.

But in the mean time, this works for me. I use terminal to navigate into the binary and run the following commands

```
rm CodeResources
ln -s _CodeSignature/CodeResources CodeResources
```

This deletes the invalid CodeResources file and replaces it with the required symbolic link to _CodeSignature/CodeResources.

Comment: This is out of date but people might still stumble upon this post so here's an update - I reinstalled my OS and the problem disappeared. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this issue.  It turned out, I had two info.plist files in my resources folder (one for the iPhone version and another for the iPad version).  Once I took care of that, the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem. Turns out the project file project.pbxproj in Project.xcodeproj had been corrupted while uploading to an SVN server.
My solution was simply to revert to an older revision, which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to: 
1. Enter the AppName.app folder 
2. Create a file named CodeResources 
3. Open the file with a plain text editor 
4. Type in _CodeSignature/CodeResources (The path where the actual CodeResources file is.)
{The app will now know where the CodeResources file is, and will have an account for all the files in the .app folder.}