# Upload iphone app error "The CodeResources file must be a symbolic link ...."

Tags: iphone, distribution, symlink, codesign

I have been working on this issue for over a week with no luck and tried every possible solution e.g. delete and reinstall certificates, profiles, and everything seems to be ok.

My problem show up when I try to upload with Application Uploader where it shows ""The CodeResources file must be a symbolic link .... " error , so I checked my application package and found CodeResources as symbolic and properly linked to "_CodeSignature/CodeResources"

To make sure I deleted "CodeResources" file and recreate symbolic link to "_CodeSignature/CodeResources" using command: ln -s _CodeSignature/CodeResources CodeResources

But even this didn't solve my problem. So I thought to remove "CodeResources" then zip package and try to upload... Surprisingly Application Loader accepted it and start uploading!!

I have searched all over internet and tried all solutions I found but didn't solve this irritating problem.

BTW, I tried to zip the app package with -y parameter but still no luck

Kindly assist me to solve it

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [update iphone app "CodeResources file must be a symoblic link"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516300/update-iphone-app-coderesources-file-must-be-a-symoblic-link)

Comment: I have seen this post but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Finally, uploaded app successfully .

I don't know exactly what was the issue, but glad that my app has been uploaded successfully

Anyhow, all I did was running disk utility and repair permissions (several times). and put English language in the top of languages list (System preferences -> Language & Text) then reboot system before I try to upload.

Thanks